# Cannot create a new virtual sink with pulse audio without feedback on the main sink by default instead of only selected sinks using it

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I am using Linux, Ubuntu, with `pulse audio` and want to apply an audio effect to an audio source (eg microphone) and pipe that to a new sink which can be used by either arecord or another application and use generally but I get feedback on the main sink (not isolated).

I create a virtual sink called `VirtualSink` using the module, *module-null-sink* via:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=VirtualSink sink_properties=device.description=Virtual_Sink
```

I get the list of all the sources which includes my microphone source `pactl list sources short` and then run ffmpeg to use the microphone source to apply an echo and pass that into the monitor of the VirtualSink via:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i <mic-source> -af "aecho=0.8:0.9:1000:0.3" -f pulse "VirtualSink.monitor"
```

The virtual sink does get created, it can be seen by applications such as arecord/Skype, the stream passes through, but the problems:

- The audio from the microphone can be heard through the speakers/earphones (being directed to the application and to the default sink output)
- The sound is heard on the speakers/earphones after a few seconds of delay (some kind of feedback)

I looked at `pavucontrol` and tried muting and altering controls there but it did not make a difference. It only at times muted the stream without solving any of the 2 problems. Is the issue maybe with ffmpeg that streams to the default sink automatically, or that the OS directs any new sinks to the general overarching sink as well? Is there a configuration that is missing?

*How can I create the sink, stream audio to it from a source and not have the feedback?*